# A verificação de email funciona, mas depois não "atualiza" quando digito e email correto

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Quando digito um email já cadastrado ele exibe a mensagem dizendo que o email ja esta em uso e desabilita o botão de submit, porém quando digito o email certo a mensagem não some, como fazer para quando o email estiver correto a mensagem sair e o botao abilitar?

verificaEmail.php

```
    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $emailPostado = $_POST['email'];

    #Conecta banco de dados 
    include('conn.php');
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE email = '{$emailPostado}'") or print mysql_error();

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) {
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Email já cadastrado')); 
        }

}
?>
```

```html
<div class="wrap-input100">
  <input class="input100" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <div class="resposta" id='resposta'></div>
</div>

<button class="login100-form-btn" id="submit">Cadastrar</button>

<script>
  //Verifica email
  var email = $("#email");
  email.change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'verificaEmail.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        "email": email.val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("#resposta").text(data.email);
        $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderia colocar um `else` na verificação do email no PHP retornando um valor na chave `email`, como um "ok", por exemplo:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) {
   echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Email já cadastrado')); 
}else{
   echo '{"email": "ok"}';
}
```

E no JavaScript você usa operadores ternários para esvaziar/preencher a div e habilitar/desabilitar o botão de acordo com o retorno:

```
$("#resposta").text(data.email === "ok" ? '' : data.email);
$("#submit").attr("disabled", data.email === "ok" ? false : true);
```

### Dica

Se o retorno esperado for sempre um JSON, então em vez de converter o retorno com `$.parseJSON(data);` você pode adicionar uma opção no AJAX que já faz isso. Basta acrescentar `dataType: "json",` no AJAX e remover a linha `data = $.parseJSON(data);` no `success`.